# Date picker problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a date picker in my content page

```
<td>
  <asp:TextBox ID='txtFrom' AutoPostBack='false' MaxLength='10' runat='server' ToolTip="Enter From Date"></asp:TextBox>
  <img id="imgdate" src="images/date.gif" />  
</td>
```

in master form I have this script

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#txtFrom').datepicker();
    $('#imgdate').click(function () {
      $('#txtFrom').datepicker('show');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Nothing working when I click on the image button ..

I have the following reference in master page

Same form I have another from date which using html input type text which work fine ..

Any idea?

Comment: Please give a more detailed description of the problem, any javascript errors? maybe a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: It looks good to me, did you properly include dependencies? any console errors?

Comment: I think you have not added all js files required for datepicker. If you are using jquery date picker first add jquery via script tag and then add datepicker js file in your html code.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I think your TextBox might not have the ID you expect it to be.

You should either use this in your javascript part to determine the id of the control:

```
<%= FindControl("txtFrom").ClientID %>
```

or set the `ClientId` of the `TextBox` control:

```
<asp:TextBox ClientID='txtFrom' ...></asp:TextBox>
```

or set the `ClientIdMode` of the `TextBox` control to `Static`:

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode='Static' ...></asp:TextBox>
```

More info in this good [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-Client-ID-Feature) article.